# Headers are NOT Loading on the Request

Tags: jmeter

The Sample Response is Displayed as Below after Executing a Request for 15 min in jmeter

/*Load time:900017
Connect Time:0
Latency:0
Size in bytes:3172
Sent bytes:0
Headers size in bytes:0
Body size in bytes:3172
Sample Count:1
Error Count:1
Data type ("text"|"bin"|""):text
Response code:Non HTTP response code: java.net.SocketException
Response message:Non HTTP response message: Socket closed

HTTPSampleResult fields:
ContentType:
DataEncoding: null*/

Logs :
/*WARN o.a.j.m.SampleTimeout: Call Done interrupting HTTPSamplerProxy @656569135 'buildAdvisorList'  took 0.0015327 secs
*/

WARN o.a.j.m.SampleTimeout: Call Done interrupting HTTPSamplerProxy @656569135 'buildAdvisorList'  took 0.0015327 secs

Comment: Please clarify what your question is, what you've tried so far, and how exactly the results differ from what you expect/want. More information about [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

Headers are NOT loading because you are NOT getting the RESPONSE.

> Headers size in bytes:0

and you're NOT getting the RESPONSE because YOU are CLOSING the connection YOURSELF with [Sample Timeout](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Sample_Timeout) PreProcessor.

> java.net.SocketException Response message:Non HTTP response message: Socket closed

If your request takes longer than 15 minutes either increase the timeout in the Sample Timeout preprocessor or disable/remove it.

In case you're able to get the response in 15 minutes (or less) using a real browser - make sure that JMeter is configured to behave like a real browser and sends the same request, pay attention to:

- URL
- request [headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers)
- request payload

cross check the request which is sent by JMeter with the one(s) sent by the real browser using a [sniffer tool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packet_analyzer). My expectation is that once you [amend JMeter configuration so it will send the same request as the real browser](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser) does - you will get the same response as the browser does including headers.

Comment: Dmitri T, This Issue is eating of my time it is great if you help me out of this,,,

Below are the sampler Results : 

/*Thread Name:CRM_Bulk_ADV_Cache_Drop_EVAL 1-1
Sample Start:2024-01-25 11:33:50 UTC
Load time:900009
Connect Time:0
Latency:0
Size in bytes:3172
Sent bytes:0
Headers size in bytes:0
Body size in bytes:3172
Sample Count:1
Error Count:1
Data type ("text"|"bin"|""):text
Response code:Non HTTP response code: java.net.SocketException
Response message:Non HTTP response message: Socket closed


HTTPSampleResult fields:
ContentType: 
DataEncoding: null */

Comment: It is Actually A Request which takes 8 min to respond for single User (Same on Browser also), But here on Browser it is loading fine, when we run JMX file it is Not Responding and showing above in sampler Response-----Dmitri T, Thanks in Advance